# access to nested data

Tags: python

I need to access structured data in a nested way but I didn't understand how to do it.

The data is structured in this way:

```
{'function':'data_chip',
 'group_id': 172,
 'Types': [
    {'TMS0202':'SR-20',
     'TMS0207':'SR-22',
     'TMS0201': 'TI-4000',
     'TMS0203': 'TI-450'
    }
 ]
}
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to do?

Comment: I should access the information in the 'Types' subtree

Answer (score 1):

To access the top-level data, use a single dictionary index:

```
data['function'] —> 'data chip'
```

To access the data in the `Types` key, you need to access the list first then the dictionary inside it:

```
data['Types'][0]['TMS0202'] —> 'SR-20'
```

Each time you get a level deeper, consider what data type you now need to access. If it is a `dict` you need the keys, if it is a `list` you need the integer index. Each level you access is another retrieval using square brackets:

```
data[key][index][key]
```

Answer (score 1):

Is there a particular part you're trying to access?

Here are a few examples:

```
$ python
Python 3.7.2 (default, Dec 27 2018, 07:35:06) 
[Clang 10.0.0 (clang-1000.11.45.5)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> data = {'function':'data_chip',
...  'group_id': 172,
...  'Types': [
...     {'TMS0202':'SR-20',
...      'TMS0207':'SR-22',
...      'TMS0201': 'TI-4000',
...      'TMS0203': 'TI-450'
...     }
...  ]
... }
>>> data['function']
'data_chip'
>>> data['Types'][0]['TMS0202']
'SR-20'
>>> data['group_id']
172
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Very explanatory!

Answer (score 0):

to access nested data you could using
`data['keyword']` or `data.get('keyword', default value)`

In your case that you want information on types (I assumed you want all data) you could looping on types, using something like:

```
datas = {'function':'data_chip',
 'group_id': 172,
 'Types': [
    {'TMS0202':'SR-20',
     'TMS0207':'SR-22',
     'TMS0201': 'TI-4000',
     'TMS0203': 'TI-450'
    }
 ]
}

for data in datas['types']:
    put your code here
```